# make bubble arround text in uitextview?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I am working on an application which has the same user interface as iPhone SMS Application. 
I want to make a "To" text field to add multiple contacts from the address book.

How can I make the blue bubble in text after selecting the contact from the address book?
Also, I want to make the message text field auto resize - when the given frame ends, it will start scrolling down.

Answer (score 2):

You'll most likely want to use a UIWebView, or a completely custom UIView, rather than a UITextView. Those bubbles are all custom drawn, there's no API for using them. You'll have to place each chunk of text, and then draw the bubble around it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . can you provide any sample code to do this.

Comment: there's an awful lot to this; I suggest you read up on CoreGraphics and UIScrollView, as those will be two subjects you'll use here.

Answer (score 0):

For the message you need UITextView

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     textField.frame = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y-(textField.contentSize.height-textField.frame.size.height), textField.frame.size.width, textField.contentSize.height)
     return YES;
}
```